# Downloading attachments

Tags: gmail

Google took me to this site. Gmail app download button is opaque. Apparently sdcard/Downloads is the plaCe to look. Download exists on my Sony tablet but does not include the file I "downloaded". is it just a typo by your colleague? Anywhere this stuff is documented? We shouldn't just have to guess. Makes me nostalgic for Windows or old bog-standard Unix!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the downloaded attachments in `/sdcard/documents/` directory. If you can't find it then use a file explorer app like [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en) to search for it.